# draw shapes like circles, oval, ractangles dynamically in android

Tags: android

I am a newbie in android. I want to draw different shapes like circle,rectangle,oval etc dynamically in android, as in other pdf readers like repligo etc.
Please suggest me...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html Check for Fingerpaint sample.

Comment: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-canvas-your-android-apps-part-2

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion, but it will be more helpfull for me if someone can explain via code..